# How to change cursor while dragging over CSS

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm coding a script and I need to **drag and drop** some list items to a div, but I have a `cursor: default;` in that css code and when I'm dragging that list item over the div, it doesn't change the cursor.

How can I set the cursor of the **jQuery UI** to `!important` or something like that?

Thank you and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in Jquery UI API you need to define it like this:

$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
          cursor:"crosshair"
        });

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; background:green; }
  </style>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      cursor:"crosshair"
    });
  });
  </script>

 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag this</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have it like that, but I also have a cursor: default; in my css, so when I drag over the div with that css, the cursor of css prevails over the cursor jQuery.

Comment: You shall load jquery ui library after your main css so that it gets overridden by jquery ui. Can you post  a live link or a chunk of your code?